# Is it possible to generate an embedded token for a Power BI report that doesn't require the viewer to be logged in?

Tags: php, oauth, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

For a client, I'm working on a project integrating their dashboards on narrowcasting displays.

I'm looking for a way to generate embedded tokens for Power BI dashboards and reports that can display the dashboard/report on a browser that is NOT logged in to their Power BI accounts.

The documentation is very double in this regard, since some API docs state that a viewer must be logged in, while some indicate that this isn't the case.
I haven't gotten any luck experimenting with this, since for every scope I need more, I need to jump through a lot of hoops to be approved by the companies administrator.

Is this even possible and if so: what end-points and scenario should I use?
I have an approved Azure AD app and a functional user that can access Power BI.

Not that it really matters, but the application is built in PHP, but I can just as easy switch to Node.JS to fetch the necessary embed tokens.

Every experiment I've done indicated that I should be logged in.

Opening generated embed URL's from Power BI itself in incognito mode results in me having to log in.
Generating new embedded URL's from some Power BI endpoints fail, because I need some kind of administrator approval (indicated by the OAuth request dialog).

Comment: The only ways to consume Power BI without having a Power BI license (even Free), thus without the need to log in, are [Publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web) (which is very limited and will make your data publicly available - usually you have to avoid that) and [Embed for your customers, a.k.a. app-owns-data scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core). I recommend the latter one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll look into the customer scenario.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Embed for your customer's application documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core). For authentication you can use either master user or service principal authentication methods. MSFT recommends using service principal authentication.  If you wish to migrate to NodeJS, Refer to [Node JS Developer Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/NodeJS/Embed%20for%20your%20customers).

If you want to use it in your PHP application, you need to authenticate using clientCredenetials for service principal authentication and get Embed parameters using REST APIs.

Another workaround is that you can also create a function in azure and implement code to get embed parameters and Get the Function URL. Here you are authenticating in azure portal. Once you get function url, you can embed your report in any language by fetching the embed parameters from URL.

Refer to my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/KotanaSai21/powerbi-embedded-React-demo) how to create function URL if you face any difficulties. Fetch  the URL in your PHP application to get embed parameters and then embed the report.

Comment: It's upto you, how you want to embed report. Feel free to reach out if you face any other issues :)

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. The problem is that I don't have any access to the customer's Azure environment. Every request has to go through an Azure admin.

I will go with the "Embed for your customer" scenario (with the master user angle).